# Add a specific tag (this type --> <metaphor> sentence </metaphor>) to a specific portion of text in a box?

Tags: excel, vba

The job is about annotating a corpus for textual metaphor recognition. I am working on Excel in order to export a CSV file for BERT analysis. I have two columns. The first column contains streches of texts. The second column is for my annotation: if there is a metaphor I put "metaphor", if not I put "none". However, my colleague asked me to addionally add a textual mark up to the portion of text which corresponds to a metaphor. So I am manually putting the sentence in this way: `<metaphor>` *sentence* `</metaphor>`
. I now am wondering if there is a macro or a shortcut keyboard where I just highlight the sentece I want and I press *Ctrl*+ *something* and the sentence appears within the tag specified. Thank you very much for your help.
So the following image describes how my dataset is going to be annotated [This describes how my dataset is going to be annotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSipv.png) and this is what is my aim:[the annotation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXnoZ.png). Be Aware that I added the coloure in the example only for clarification. I do not want to add colour to the tagging.

UPDATE

1. I have a two column dataset, as in the image 1. Column 1 contains sentences from an archive which have the word "immigrant". Column 2 indicates if there is a metaphor or not.
2. The annotator detect and interpret manually the presence of a metaphor. He will fill the column number 2.
3. When you find a sentence like this:

> Does the Minister recognise the challenging fact that the flow of
> economic migrants  will continue until the standard of living of the
> country?

I then interpret "the flow of economic migrants" as a meataphor.

So, I will put "the flow of economic migrants as metaphor" between `<metaphor>... </metaphor>` and I will have the following annotated sentence:

> Does the Minister recognise the challenging fact that `<metaphor>`"the
> flow of economic migrants" `</metaphor>` will continue until the
> standard of living of the country ?

I tried to record a macro as indicated in the comments above but then it cannot be run and I do not know why.

I hope I have been clear.

UPDATE 2

MOre images from the dataset

[The dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdSxE.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, I think... What do you mean by "in this *way sentence*"? Do you change the font property of the respective 'metaphor'  to be `Italics`? Or what? A picture with what is it in the cell and what you want being extracted and another one showing what you want. Is my above assumption (`Italics`) correct? If so, do you like the part of string in `Italics` to be placed between "<metaphor>" and "</metaphor>"

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I was working with no access to the laptop.
So, the change of the font is not referred to the action I need to do. I will show now.

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification question. It is good to come here from time to time, after placing a question and answer the clarification questions, if any...

Supposing that my assumption that you change the font of the text portion meaning a metaphor in Italics, please try using the next `Sub` (Copy it in a standard module):

```
Sub addMetaphorTag(c As Range)
   Dim strMeth As String, i As Long, frst As Long, last As Long, boolFrst As Boolean
   
   With c
        For i = 1 To Len(.Value)
             If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic Then
                 If Not boolFrst Then
                     boolFrst = True
                     frst = i
                 End If
             ElseIf boolFrst Then
                 last = i - 1: Exit For
             End If
        Next i
        strMeth = Mid(.Value, frst, last - frst + 1)
        .Value = left(.Value, frst - 1) & "<metaphor>" & strMeth & "</metaphor>" & Right(.Value, Len(c.Value) - last)
        'if you don't need it staying Italic, comment the next line (in CSV it does not matter, anyhow)
        .Characters(frst + 10, Len(strMeth)).Font.Italic = True 
    End With
End Sub
```

It can be tested in the following way: Select a cell having a metaphor part marked in Italics and run the next code:

```
Sub TestAddMetaphorTag()
    Dim cel As Range: Set cel = ActiveCell
    
    addMetaphorTag cel
End Sub
```

If it returns as you need, the next piece of code will process all your **active sheet**, having the marked text in "A:A" column, for cells marked as "metaphor" in column "B:B":

```
Sub AddMetaphTag()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For i = 2 To lastR
        If LCase(sh.Range("B" & i).Value) = "metaphor" Then
            AddMetaphorTag sh.Range("A" & i)
        End If
   Next i
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

If the range to be processed is huge, the code can be adapted to be faster, **if you do not need the initially `Italics` part to remain in `Italics`**...

If you want to add a shortcut to run the macro, please proceed in the next way:

a. Go in `Developer` Tab and press `Macros` from first `Code` section.

b. In the `Macro Name` list, find and select `AddMetaphTag` and press `Options...` from bottom right window.

c. Fill the key you want in the small text box, add a description (if you want) and and press `OK`. But take care to not overwrite some important already used such shortcuts (a, s, f, h, p etc.).

If you do not see `Developer` Tab on your Ribbon, go `File` -> `Options` -> `Customize Ribbon` (from the left side) and in the opening window, to the right you will see `Main Tabs`, where you should check `Developer` and press `OK`...

Comment: I am sorry, I was working. I have answered to your clarification. Maybe, it is clearer?

Comment: @Dario Del Fante I am afraid that nobody can understand something from your "clarification", **since you did not show ANYTHING, exactly from the cell where such a "metaphor" exist**, before processing. It looks we do not speak the same language, and I am not referring to English, no offence... You should, at least, try putting in our place. **Based on WHAT  to process the cell value** in the way you want, if this is only in your mind? Should the font be red? Neither in your example picture it is not... Only part of it.

Comment: Ok. I will try to be as clear as possible. 
I will update my question above. You are right. We do not speak the same language.

Comment: @Dario Del Fante Please, do it fast. No something else needed than showing **how you mark the respective text portion**. If you can do that **in words**, it will be enough, if clear. Isn't it red? I will leave my office in about 20 minutes and I will be available only after some hours when I will be at home.

Comment: I am sorry. It is my second time here. Anyway, I think I have explained my problem. I do not know why you don't see any image, right?

Comment: @Dario Del Fante **Did you look to the first image you are talking about**? I mean, **here following the link in the question**... The single case to be processed has only "Sentence" text... What should I understand from this string, in terms of processing logic?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The text to be analysed is only in column 1. 
I will manually add the info if we have a metaphor or not in column 2.
Then, additionally, I will put the metaphor identified in column 1 whinin the tag `<metaphor>`...`</metaphor>`. This will be applied in the same box - in the column 1.

Comment: @Dario Del Fante What do you see in the first picture, in A:A column cell, where "Metaphor" exists in B:B? What **text to be analyzed** do you show? **Based on what** to reach the desired result from the second picture? Do you understand what I am talking about? Should the metaphor be marked **by red font**?

Comment: So.
1- Column A:A contains the sentences from the dataset and Column B:B is manually filled by myself.
2 - I can't show you all the text, but there are 130 different rows in the Column A:A. I manually read all the sentences and I interpret if we have a metaphor.
3- I am sorry for the colour. I coloured because it could have been useful to understand. But I do not need the colour.
Concretely, this is my idea: I go in the different rows in COLUMN A:A. I highlight with the pointer the sentence with metaphor and then by using a shortkey I autmatically add the tag `<metaphor>`...`</metaphor>`.

Comment: I am driving now. How old are you?

Comment: No worries. I am not in a hurry! Thank you for your help.
I honestly do not understand the reason why you are asking this to me. 
Anyway, I am 30.

Comment: What do you mea by "I highlight with the pointer the sentence"?

Comment: So, I was trying to be really precise --> I just meant "using the mouse".

Comment: To select part of the text? VBA does not work if a cell is edited! Select the sentence, press the *I* button to make selection font Italic and  write metaphor in B:B column. You can select the marked cell from A:A and run TestAddMetaphorTag procedure from above, to see how it works. If you like the result, mark the sentences with Italics in all cells where you see a metaphor, mark it in B:B and run AddMetaphTag. It will process all the column...

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I was thinking about the possibility that VBA does not work if a cell is edited! So, thanks! By the way, why did you ask me my age?

Comment: @Dario Del Fante English is not my native language... I thought that maybe my language expertize is not so high and wanted to know if is the case to be more atentive in choosing the appropriate words, since you looked not understanding what I was asking in the way as explained... Now, could you use the code or not? If still not, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk applications installed? If so, I would like to connect to your computer and show how to use the code...